# How to Convert from Point to Continuous Raster in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, rasterization, geoprocessing-framework

I have a vector point dataset that I would like to convert to raster. The point-to-raster conversion tool creates a raster grid with spaces between each grid cell. I want to create a 'continuous' raster whereby each grid cell expands outwards until its' borders meet with the adjacent cell's borders.

I find the interpolation tools under spatial analysis to be unsatisfactory (spline is the closest I come to satisfactory). I do not want to smooth my data when I put it in raster form (ie I want to keep peaks and valleys in data).

Is there a geoprocessing tool that gets at what I am attempting to do?

Comment: I've never seen a raster with cells that don't meet at their edges. What is the distance between your points? You need to set a cell size that is appropriate for the data. Are the points regularly spaced (i.e. in perfect rows and columns)?

Comment: @jbchurchill the cells are in a 2.5' arc grid, and as such, the x and y distance between each grid cell and its neighbor changes slightly as the latitude increases.

Comment: The method I have settled on is to convert points to thiessen polygons. Then I do polygon to raster conversion. This method seems to work well.

Comment: You could also use the point to raster to create dots (or not) and then Euclidean Allocation to 'fill' the values. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000001m000000.htm (Spatial Analyst required) can either work from the raster or from points if you supply source_field to allocate. GDAL has a utility called GDAL_Grid which would do what you're after also - just saying.